# How do you turn off SIP support in weblogic server 12c

Tags: weblogic12c

How do you turn off SIP support in weblogic 12c?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable SIP support from your domain by removing references of SIP from your domain's config/config.xml file.

Shutdown WLS. Be sure to backup your config.xml file before making any changes Then remove the following:

```
<network-access-point>
  <name>sip</name>
  <protocol>sip</protocol>
  <listen-port>5060</listen-port>
  <public-port>5060</public-port>
  <http-enabled-for-this-protocol>false</http-enabled-for-this-protocol>
  <outbound-enabled>true</outbound-enabled>
</network-access-point>
<network-access-point>
  <name>sips</name>
  <protocol>sips</protocol>
  <listen-port>5061</listen-port>
  <public-port>5061</public-port>
  <http-enabled-for-this-protocol>false</http-enabled-for-this-protocol>
  <outbound-enabled>true</outbound-enabled>
</network-access-point>
```

Towards the end remove this:

```
<custom-resource>
    <name>sipserver</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <descriptor-file-name>custom/sipserver.xml</descriptor-file-name>
    <resource-class>com.bea.wcp.sip.management.descriptor.resource.SipServerResource</resource-class>
    <descriptor-bean-class>com.bea.wcp.sip.management.descriptor.beans.SipServerBean</descriptor-bean-class>
  </custom-resource>
```

When you start WLS, SIP will not be started. This worked wonderfully for my WLS 12c domain.

Comment: If you are getting issues trying to deploy an app on weblogic, you'd better create a new domain from scratch without SIP support. Editing the config file didn't fix deployment issues in my case, but creating a new domain (that is without SIP support) did